# Extending ImageItem and adding fields

Tags: 8

My goal is to create a custom field, with a combination of properties -- Heading, Body, Image -- to produce, for instance, a hero component. The image, in my case, would be optional.

I can't use paragraphs, since it needs to be a field on the node but also a block to be displayed outside of its layout. See image below...

[image: Like this]

I've accomplished everything so far, thanks to this article as a springboard, with a single (important) exception:
https://github.com/WiddleWabbit/Drupal-ExtendedImage/blob/main/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/ExtendedImageField.php

If an image isn't uploaded at the time of node save, the supplemental fields (heading, body) don't save and there is no database entry.

I'm not sure how to make the image, itself, optional and still save the other fields.

Here is where I'm at:
https://github.com/DrupalPhil/ExtendImageItem/blob/master/Field/FieldType/HeroItem.php

Comment: `I can't use paragraphs, since it needs to be a field on the node but also a block to be displayed outside of its layout.` - Why does that rule out Paragraphs? You can do all your requirements with Paragraphs, without any code.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't rule out Paragraphs absolutely. I would need custom code to display the paragraph content outside of the node region, though. See the image I added above. Also, at this point, I've spent enough time on this that I'm just eager to know how it's done.

Comment: The logic for displaying a field outside the main content is not different than displaying a paragraph outside the main content. For learning purposes, you most likely need to override the [isEmpty](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/function/EntityReferenceItem%3A%3AisEmpty/8.2.x) function of the base field. But for production I definitly would recommend using Paragraphs for this.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this here, to no avail: https://github.com/DrupalPhil/ExtendImageItem/blob/master/Field/FieldType/HeroItem.php#L91